# I am plotting the output of the model in machine learning but i don't know what plt.plot... line of code do? Can anyone explain that line

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-learn

```
plt.scatter(train.ENGINESIZE, train.CO2EMISSIONS,  color='blue')
plt.plot(train_x, regr.coef_[0][0]*train_x + regr.intercept_[0], '-r') #this line of code
plt.xlabel("Engine size")
plt.ylabel("Emission")
```

Comment: You should ask a more specific question. Have you tried looking at the documentation for the "plot" function? What was it there that you are confused about? What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Also, as a future reference, please give more indications on the nature of the input data, such as `train_x`, or `regr`. Otherwise, any answer will be based on "assumptions"

Comment: Ok bro in future I will definitely take care

Answer (score 0):

`regr` is presumably a [linear regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression) model. Note such model is simply the input data times a weight vector plus the intercept, so with `regr.coef_[0][0]*train_x + regr.intercept_[0]`, we are plotting the resulting slope output by the model, along with the scattered input data, and seing how good of a fit the model is.

Answer (score 0):

You basically give many parameters in plot function..
plt.plot(train_x, (regr.coef_[0][0]*train_x + regr.intercept_[0]), '-r')

This work for me.